# Does using VPN or encryption on an Android phone do anything since Google knows who is logged into the phone?

Tags: encryption, android, vpn, google

Is it worth paying for a VPN to protect myself from Google tracking since, on an Android phone, you're logged into a Google account and Google knows who you are, anyway?

Google can still track your activities depending on what Android OS reports to them. A related question would be whether encrypted messaging and email apps protect you on an Android since, once again, the OS is designed by Google and the OS can theoretically see the decrypted messages.

Comment: Is there a component of Google tracking in particular you think the VPN would protect against in this case?

Comment: I don't, but a lot of security-minded people recommend using VPNs. So this question is basically asking if it's a waste of money.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specifically regarding VPNs, they are often marketed as a panacea to solve all security and privacy problems. While they can solve some problems, unfortunately much of it is just false hype and exaggerated for advertisement purposes.

VPNs protect network transit point-to-point from your device to the VPN server. They do not protect against anything outside of that. Google runs apps and services on the device that can collect data such as location (using GPS and nearby WiFi networks) and other usage data (browser history, app data backups, etc.). None of these things are affected by your network setup (e.g. VPN); as long as there is a working connection, things will be reported back to Google.

The only way to avoid Google tracking is to not use Google products. There are custom Android distributions (custom ROMs) that completely eschew Google's proprietary services, but many apps that rely on these services will break. Or, you could try to use an adblocker to block all Google related domains, but this would be very difficult.

Of course, you can't completely escape Google since they do all sorts of active and passive tracking across the internet.

Comment: If I had a nickel everytime a VPN provider shamelessly overexaggerated the security benefits of using a VPN provider, I could buy a three-year subscription to ██████VPN and enjoy the countless benefity of a VPN provider today!

Comment: Thank you, multi, you've answered my question and confirmed my fears. For all intents and purposes, I can't escape Google, and a VPN for that specific purpose would just be a waste of money.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you think of Google as a malicious adversary that is willing to go to any length to track you, then certainly the situation does seem rather hopeless. But just because Android *can* send decrypted messaging data to Google without your consent doesn't mean it will. While Android's default privacy settings are admittedly not so privacy-friendly, Google has a reputation to protect and so it is in their best interest to ensure that Android's privacy settings do what they say they do, unless they want to subject themselves to lawsuits and have users flock from Android en masse.

The same problem arguably exists for other operating systems too. Apple could make their phones send whatever data to Apple they want, or push an update that would do so. Same goes for Microsoft and Windows. But all of these companies also have a commercial interest in ensuring that the privacy settings do what they say they do. Ultimately you need to trust your operating system, which means either trusting the commercial entity that makes it, or in the case of Linux distros, the people who put it together.

The other consideration is, what do you think of as your primary threats? If I hypothetically trusted Google but used public Wifi hotspots often, for example, then I might be perfectly okay with Google seeing my activity as long as it prevents random strangers from snooping on my Wifi. If you are trying to protect yourself, you need to be explicit about *what* you're protecting yourself against.

Comment: Thanks, and very good point about being explicit on what the threat is. In this case, my concerns are general tracking and loss of privacy to Google, Facebook, and other large corporations. I realize it's an impersonal machine tracking me, not a person, and that it's for advertising purposes, but I don't like it nonetheless and there are always data breaches that could result in actual people exploiting my data.